# Django queryset group by and count distincts

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

In my django application, I have a set of donation, which I want to make statistics on. For each donation, a person is linked with his email address.

I want to compute for each month, the number of donors, that is the number of unique email addess.

So far I have:

```
# filter all donations by month
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')
qs = Donation.objects.extra({'month': truncate_date})

# group by months and annotate each with the count of emails
donors = qs.values('month').annotate(count=Count('email')).order_by('month')
```

This works well, I get a monthly report of all email donors, but as I got duplicate in email, it does not filter email by unique values.

The current database used is Postgresql.

How this can be done?

Comment: Are you using postgres?

Comment: Yes, I'll add this in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Count` takes a [`distinct` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct), so you can do:

```
donors = qs.values('month').annotate(count=Count('email', distinct=True)).order_by('month')
```